# Get indices of elements that are greater than a threshold in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array:

```py
x = np.array([
 [  1.92043482e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.41005634e-03,   0.00000000e+00,
    7.19330120e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.42886875e-04,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   9.79279411e-05,   7.88888657e-04,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   1.40425916e-01,   0.00000000e+00,   1.13955893e-02,
    7.36868947e-03,   3.67091988e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.72037105e-03,   1.72377961e-03,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.19532061e-01,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   3.37249481e-04,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.75111492e-03,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   1.12639313e-02],
 [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.10271735e-04,   5.98736562e-04,
    6.77961628e-04,   7.49569659e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    2.91697850e-03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   3.30257021e-04,   2.46629275e-04,
    0.00000000e+00,   1.87586441e-02,   6.49103144e-04,   0.00000000e+00,
    1.19046355e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.69499898e-03,
    1.48525386e-02,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.18803119e-03,
    3.93100829e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.76245304e-04,   2.79537738e-02,
    0.00000000e+00,   1.20738457e-03,   9.74669064e-06,   7.18680093e-04,
    1.61546793e-02,   3.49360861e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

How do I get indices of the elements that are greater than `0.01`?

Right now, I'm doing `t = np.argmax(x, axis=1)` to get the index of the maximum value from each and the result of it is: `[21 35]`. How do I achieve the above?

Answer (score 66):

You can use `np.argwhere` to return the indices of all the entries in an array matching a boolean condition:

```
>>> x = np.array([[0,0.2,0.5],[0.05,0.01,0]])

>>> np.argwhere(x > 0.01)
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: Umm, I think I'm not clear on how to interpret the np array. In (array([0, 1]), array([1, 0])), why is it array[1,0] and not [0,1]?

Comment: because they're numpy objects

Comment: I'm not sure if that is giving me the correct result. I did t = np.where(x > 0.01, and the output I got was: (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([21, 23, 34, 49, 17, 24, 35, 40])). But, the first element doesn't even have 21 in it, which is returned when using argmax.

Comment: oh sorry actually the first array is the x coordinates and the second array is the y coordinates, you need to zip them to get the x-y coordinates, i'll edit my answer

Comment: actually you use `argwhere`

Answer (score 1):

One can also use `np.nonzero()` to get a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension of `x` containing the indices where the condition is True.

```py
x_indices, y_indices = np.nonzero(x > 0.01)
# (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([21, 23, 34, 49, 17, 24, 35, 40], dtype=int64))
```

A nice thing about it is that it can be used to index an array right away. For example, if we want to filter the elements that are greater than 0.01, then

```py
x[np.nonzero(x>0.01)]
```

`nonzero` groups indices by dimension while `argwhere` groups by element (which is just looking at the same thing from a different side), so the following is True:

```py
(np.argwhere(x>0.01).T == np.nonzero(x>0.01)).all()   # True
```